# Android APK Expansion testing with multiple accounts

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files, android-account

My application is a paid application which is also using apk expansion library.

For testing I have added a test account in my developer console say

xyz@gmail.com

And it's working as expected (Expansion files are downloaded) when I am testing with a device which was registered with above account first.

But the problem occurred when I installed a signed apk to a device which is already registered with

abc@gmail.com

I have added xyz@gmail.com account before the installation of signed apk, And as a checklist I made sure Gmail and Google Play are working properly with this account.

But upon running the app, I have got the error

"Download failed because you may not have purchased the app".

What should I do to test the application in above condition? Do I need to remove abc@gmail.com? Or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done and final.

Android LVL aka Licencing verification library only fetches `primary account` (Google account you registered first for your device) to work with.

Quoting android's original [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html)

> The Google Play client collects the necessary information about the user and the device, such as the device's **primary Google account username**, IMSI, and other information. It then sends the license check request to the server on behalf of your application.